# How to select values from a dataframe by a series of column names?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
    A   B
0   1   4
1   2   5
2   3   6
```

And a series `s`:

```
0    A
1    B
2    A
```

Now I want to pick values from `df` with column names specified in `s`. The expected result is:

```
0    1  <- from column A
1    5  <- from column B
2    3  <- from column A
```

How can I get this done efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) for indices by `Series` and select values by numpy indexing in `2d array`:

```
a = df.to_numpy()
b = a[np.arange(len(df)), df.columns.get_indexer(s)]
print (b)
[1 5 3]
```

---

```
s1 = pd.Series(b, s.index)
print (s1)
0    1
1    5
2    3
dtype: int64
```